# mssgbox alerted through boolean in vb syntax

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, boolean

i made a maze (using a tutorial at mdsn.com) in vb but u r able to go around the maze and straight to the finish so i tried adding a Boolean called cheater which changes to true when the user exits the form and then gives u a mssgbox saying cheater instead of winner if u enter the label i used for finish afterward however it gives me cheater all the time

heres the code im focusing on the last sub

```
Public Class Form

Dim cheater As Boolean

Private BumpSoundPlayer = New System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:\Windows\Media\chord.wav")

Private finishSoundPlayer = New System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:\Windows\Media\tada.wav")

'Private cheaterSoundPlayer = New System.Media.SoundPlayer("C:\Windows\Media\\W\windows_critical_stop.wav")

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    MoveToStart()
End Sub

Private Sub MoveToStart()
    Dim startingPoint = Panel1.Location
    startingPoint.Offset(40, 20)
    Cursor.Position = PointToScreen(startingPoint)
    cheater = False
End Sub

Private Sub wall_MouseEnter() Handles Label8.MouseEnter, Label9.MouseEnter, Label7.MouseEnter, Label60.MouseEnter, Label6.MouseEnter, Label59.MouseEnter, Label58.MouseEnter, Label57.MouseEnter, Label56.MouseEnter, Label55.MouseEnter, Label54.MouseEnter, Label53.MouseEnter, Label52.MouseEnter, Label51.MouseEnter, Label50.MouseEnter, Label5.MouseEnter, Label49.MouseEnter, Label48.MouseEnter, Label47.MouseEnter, Label46.MouseEnter, Label45.MouseEnter, Label44.MouseEnter, Label43.MouseEnter, Label42.MouseEnter, Label41.MouseEnter, Label40.MouseEnter, Label4.MouseEnter, Label39.MouseEnter, Label38.MouseEnter, Label37.MouseEnter, Label36.MouseEnter, Label35.MouseEnter, Label34.MouseEnter, Label33.MouseEnter, Label32.MouseEnter, Label31.MouseEnter, Label30.MouseEnter, Label3.MouseEnter, Label29.MouseEnter, Label28.MouseEnter, Label27.MouseEnter, Label26.MouseEnter, Label25.MouseEnter, Label24.MouseEnter, Label23.MouseEnter, Label22.MouseEnter, Label21.MouseEnter, Label20.MouseEnter, Label2.MouseEnter, Label19.MouseEnter, Label18.MouseEnter, Label17.MouseEnter, Label16.MouseEnter, Label15.MouseEnter, Label14.MouseEnter, Label13.MouseEnter, Label12.MouseEnter, Label11.MouseEnter, Label10.MouseEnter, Label1.MouseEnter
    BumpSoundPlayer.play()
    MoveToStart()
End Sub


Private Sub Panel1_MouseLeave() Handles Panel1.MouseLeave
    cheater = True
End Sub

Private Sub FinishLabel_MouseEnter() Handles FinishLabel.MouseEnter
    If cheater = True Then
        'cheaterSoundPlayer.play()
        MessageBox.Show("sneaky little cheater")
        MoveToStart()
    Else
        finishSoundPlayer.play()
        MessageBox.Show("yay you did it")
        'Close()
        MoveToStart()
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is not VBA - please re-tag your question (VB.NET?)

Comment: As soon as you enter FinishedLabel, you have left Panel1, so your MouseLeave event will fire and make cheater = true

Comment: so any label even inside panel1 will b considered leaving panel1? and if so do u know what will work?

Comment: Yep, I just tried it by putting a label in a panel and setting some simple message boxes in each event.  The panel message fired first every time.  I have an idea on what you can do, but give me a minute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments above, an exited controls MouseLeave event fires before another control's MouseEnter event.  The solution below works (though it is a bit cludgy and there is probably a more elegant way to do it).

Add a Timer into the form.

```
Dim cheaterCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub Panel1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseEnter
    Timer1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseLeave
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.MouseEnter
    If cheaterCount >= 1 Then 'this equates to 1/10th second, but you can change this to whatever time interval you think is a valid time frame to move from your panel to the label.
        MsgBox("Cheater")
    Else
        MsgBox("Okay")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    cheaterCount += 1
End Sub
```

Comment: um ye it works but as u said its pretty backward im looking for something more straight forward and understandable but thank you anyway

Comment: anyway i found a better method i added another label at the end of the maze with mouseenter event which assigns false to cheater so if they do the maze properly it will work again thank u